# Cannot upload images laravel

Tags: laravel, image, path, upload

I uploaded my files on my server, but I cannot change my root folder to public via the hosting company, so I moved the files from public to the httpdocs directory, but I have now an issue with uploading images, i made this path

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'image' => 'image|nullable|max:1999'
        ]);

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . Carbon::today()->toDateString() . '.' . $extension;
            $request->file('image')->storeAs('/../Supplier/public/images', $fileNameToStore);
        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
        }
```

And when I submit my form I get this error

```
Path is outside of the defined root, path:
```

And to show the image after upload i have this code in html

```
<td><a download="retourmelding_{{$retour->firmaname}}" href="/storage/images/{{$retour->images}}" title="Foto">
                                        <img alt="Foto" src="/storage/images/{{$retour->images}}">
                                    </a></td>
```

But locally it works perfectly

Comment: The above path is inside laravel or Outside laravel?

Comment: It's outside Laravel

Comment: Please put the laravel root folder and outside path. Both

Comment: My Laravel folder is outside the httpdocs, and the index.php is in the httpdocs

Comment: But the `storage` folder is laravel directory folder yes?

Comment: Yes, it's inside the laravel directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203105/discussion-between-amit-senjaliya-and-othman-bolal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try it:

```
$request->file('image')->storeAs(storage_path('images'), $fileNameToStore);
```

The directory definition you have made is incorrect.

`../httpdocs/storage/images/` mean is `[laravel directory]/httpdocs/storage/images/`

Use helpers for directory defination: [Helpers - Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-storage-path)

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work, when I want to open the image, firefox gives this error 
`Firefox can’t find the file at http://hb-supplier.com/storage/public/jpg_2019-11-26.jpg title=.`

Comment: Becouse `storage_path('images')` return `/storage/images/`.

Comment: So, what do I have to change

Comment: You can use `storage_path('public')` or `storage_path('public/images')` and please upload again.

Comment: I changed it, and I did a dump and die, and this was the result of it `"/home/website/Supplier/storage/public/images"
`

Comment: Is 'Supplier' your laravel directory? Normally, `$request->file('image')->storeAs(storage_path('public/images'), $fileNameToStore);` will upload your file as `[laravel directory]/storage/public/images/[your file name]`

Comment: Yes, Supplier is my Laravel directory, but in the storage directory i have a driectory called `app` and then `storage` again and then `images`

Comment: As I understand, you should define like this `storage_path('app/public/images')`

Comment: Edit your post and please share your code with more lines. I need review your code. Or use `Storage` class for upload file like `Storage::disk('local')->put($fileNameToStore, $request->file('image));`

Answer (score 0):

I would change the disk in "config \ filesystems.php" and put something like this:

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the below code:

**In config/filesystem.php**

```
'my_file' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path(),
 ],
```

**In controller**

```
 $fileNameToStore = $request->file('myfile');               
 $name = $fileNameToStore->getClientOriginalName();

 Storage::disk('my_file')->PutFileAs('images', $fileNameToStore, $name);
```

For retrieving the image in view file using the route. Because of directly can not access the `storage/images` folder.

You need to create a new function in the controller.

```
use Auth, Storage, File, Response;

public function displayImage($filename)
{       
    $path = storage_path('images/' . $filename);

    if (!File::exists($path)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);    

    return $response;
```

}

**New Route add**

```
Route::get('image/{filename}', 'YOURCONTROLLER@displayImage')->name('image.displayImage');
```

**View( Retrieving image)**

```
<img src="{{ route('image.displayImage',$image) }}" alt="" title="">
```